# expect regexp example cisco

Tags: regex, expect, cisco

Hi i am trying to make the following script.

1. We go to the device via ssh - it works
2. We execute the command and from this command we get the necessary data
   through regexp
3. We write the received data into a variable
4. execute the command using a variable

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set host [lindex $argv 0]
set user test
set pass 123456

set timeout 5

spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $user@$host
expect "*assword:" {send "$pass\r"}

expect "*#" {send "sh ip int br | i Vlan9\n"}
regexp {(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)} $expect_out(buffer) matched ip
puts "ADDRESS: $ip"

expect eof
```

but it doesn't not work..

```
expect -d ssh 192.168.18.200
expect -d ssh 192.168.18.200
expect version 5.45.4
argv[0] = expect  argv[1] = -d  argv[2] = ssh  argv[3] = 192.168.18.200
set argc 1
set argv0 "ssh"
set argv "192.168.18.200"
executing commands from command file ssh
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no test@192.168.18.200
parent: waiting for sync byte
parent: telling child to go ahead
parent: now unsynchronized from child
spawn: returns {22907}

expect: does "" (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "*assword:"? no
Password:
expect: does "\rPassword: " (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "*assword:"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) "\rPassword:"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp5"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) "\rPassword:"
send: sending "123456\r" to { exp5 }

expect: does " " (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "*#"? no


expect: does " \r\n" (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "*#"? no
test-gw#
expect: does " \r\ntest-gw#" (spawn_id exp5) match glob pattern "*#"? yes
expect: set expect_out(0,string) " \r\ntest-gw#"
expect: set expect_out(spawn_id) "exp5"
expect: set expect_out(buffer) " \r\ntest-gw#"
send: sending "sh ip int br | i Vlan9\n" to { exp5 }
can't read "ip": no such variable
    while executing
"puts "ADDRESS: $ip""
    (file "ssh" line 17)
```

**on the router it looks like this**

```
sh ip int br | i Vlan9
Vlan9                  192.168.18.200  YES NVRAM  up                    up
```

through send we execute this command, through regexp we need to pull out the address 192.168.18.200 and write it into a variable for further use

Comment: can you give input examples for legal and illegal lines? this expect seems like TCL, so you're missing capture assignment in your regexp

Comment: Run your program with `expect -d myprog.exp arg ...` -- the very verbose debugging output will show you why your patterns don't match.

Comment: no, you read my answer wrong. take my regexp and put it in your expect -re regexp place. the IP will appear in the expect_out(1,string) var.

Comment: yes i did not understand: **it work** - expect -exact "#"
send -- "sh run | i hostname\r"
set name $expect_out(buffer)
regexp {([\_A-Za-z0-9]+)} $name match hostname
puts "$hostname"

Comment: **it doesn't work** - expect -exact "#"
send -- "sh ip int br | i Vlan9\r"
set src $expect_out(buffer)
regexp {(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)} $src match ipsrc
puts "ADDRESS: $ipsrc"

Answer (score 0):

I see that expect is TCL based, so:
First of all - you have a mistake in your regexp: the quotes inside the curly braces will make the regexp look for quote marks in the input itself.
Second, if you want to do something with the string you captured, you need to assign it.
If you don't, why did you place the braces in the regexp?
See example below for regex assigning.

```
> set line "the ip is 192.35.32.0 bla bla bka"
the ip is 192.35.32.0 bla bla bka
> regexp {(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)} $line -> ip
1
> echo $ip
192.35.32.0
```

So, when converting to `expect`, the expect_out(1,string) is the same as $ip

**EDIT**
`expect -re {(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)} ...` and the results will apear at expect_out(1,string) var

Comment: Best thing you can do is edit your question to have a couple of lines you'd like to be accepted and a few line that wouldn't. currently, all you need to do to make your code work is remove the quote marks (") from the regexp

Comment: hmm, but how to make the code readable in the commentary ???

Comment: In TCL I checked, it work, but in except doesn't

Answer (score 0):

this is how it works

```
expect -exact "#"
send -- "sh ip int br | i Vlan9 \r"
expect -exact "#"
set src $expect_out(buffer)
regexp {(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)} $src match ipsrc
expect -exact "#"
send -- "ping $ipsrc\r"
```

the question arose, if we can do such checks in one script, ping / tracert, port status, how to separate them with brackets, and how to use timeout more correctly?

```
expect -exact "#"
send -- "sh int des | i main | Main\r"
expect -exact "#"
set description $expect_out(buffer)
regexp {(Gi0\/1\/0)|(Fa0\/0\/0)|(Fa0)|(Gi0)} $description match interface
expect -exact "#"
send -- "sh int $interface\r"

#expect -exact "#"
#send -- "sh ip int br | i Vlan9 \r"
#expect -exact "#"
#set src $expect_out(buffer)
#regexp {(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)} $src match ipsrc
#expect -exact "#"
#send -- "ping $ipsrc\r"
```